# How to create grouped task lists in Markdown?

Tags: gitlab, markdown, documentation, merge-request

When creating different task lists in Markdown for Gitlabs templates, Gitlabs consider all the tasks from checklist as an individual count and shows count as total number of tasklist.

Like for below template -

```
## PR Checklist

Please check if your PR fulfills the following requirements:

- [X] The commit message follows our guidelines:
- [X] Tests for the changes have been added (for bug fixes / features)
- [ ] Docs have been added / updated (for bug fixes / features)

## PR Type

What kind of change does this PR introduce?

- [X] Bugfix
- [ ] Feature
- [ ] Code style update (formatting, local variables)
- [X] Refactoring (no functional changes, no api changes)
- [ ] Build related changes
- [ ] CI related changes
- [ ] Documentation content changes
- [ ] angular.io application / infrastructure changes
- [ ] Other... Please describe:

## Does this PR introduce a breaking change?

- [ ] Yes
- [X] No
```

It shows **5 of the 14 tasks completed**. Ideally, I only want first three task lists to be considered as a task by Gitlabs and it should show **2 of the 3 tasks completed**. Please let me know if there is something in the markdown or Gitlabs by which I can achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, the [docs on task lists](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#task-lists) specify that a "task" will always add to the task counter.

If you want to keep a similar formatting to encourage users to mark which items apply, then you can use parentheses like so:

```
- ( ) task
```

The formatting is not as pretty, but it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

[GitLab 15.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/02/22/gitlab-15-9-released/#convert-a-markdown-checklist-item-to-a-task) (February 2023) proposes a new option:

> ### Convert a Markdown checklist item to a task
>
> Teams often use Markdown checklist items to outline tasks or completion
> criteria for an issue, but tracking more in-depth information related to the checklist item has always been limited and cumbersome.
>
> With the release of 15.9, you can seamlessly convert a Markdown checklist item in an issue to a task, enabling teams to have a more robust experience tracking and managing an issue’s dependencies by assigning and estimating tasks separately from issues.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_9/convert_a_markdown_checklist_item_to_a_task.png -- Convert a Markdown checklist item to a task]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/tasks.html#from-a-task-list-item) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/377307).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use task list syntax for things for non-tasks.

See the [vendor documentation for task lists](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#task-lists).

You can use [labels](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/labels.html) to categorize issues with regard to feature vs bug fix, or breaking versus non-breaking change.